# Linux EC2 can not ping Windows 2012 EC2 after modifying Security Group to allow ICMP inbound

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, ping

I've applied the following rules and still can not get a ping successfully from server 1's terminal.

All the documentation I've read so far shows that this should be working by now (sometimes takes 15 minutes to kick in). I've waited hours and rebooted with no success.

```
Server 1 (us-west-2c):
Linux: Ubuntu
Outbound Traffic: 
All traffic 0.0.0.0/0

Server 2 (us-west-2a):
Windows 2012 Server
Inbound Traffic
Custom ICMP Rule Echo Reply N/A [security group 1] (launch-wizard-1)
Custom ICMP Rule Echo Reply N/A [external IP for Server 1]/32
Custom ICMP Rule Echo Reply N/A [internal IP for Server 1]/32
```

Server 2 Windows Firewall allowing IPV4 ICMP traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `Echo Reply` should've been `Echo Response`